# Could not load PEM client certificate

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, yandex

I'm trying to use yandex kassa api,but I stuck at one point.

I have no certificate password, I have certificate.cer and private.key.

I'm working on localhost with PhpStorm. Do I have to use hosting with ssl support?

I'm getting this error:

```
could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

Here is my reference.
[Yandex Kassa](https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-kassa-example/tree/master/src)

What i am doing ?

Here is my Settings.php

```
<?php 
namespace shop;
class Settings {
public $SHOP_PASSWORD = "123456";
public $SECURITY_TYPE;
public $LOG_FILE;
public $SHOP_ID = 151;
public $CURRENCY = 10643;
public $request_source;
public $mws_cert;
public $mws_private_key;
public $mws_cert_password = "";

function __construct($SECURITY_TYPE = "PKCS7" /* MD5 | PKCS7 */, $request_source = "php://input") {
    $this->SECURITY_TYPE = $SECURITY_TYPE;
    $this->request_source = $request_source;
    $this->LOG_FILE = dirname(__FILE__)."/log.txt";
    $this->mws_cert = dirname(__FILE__)."/MWS/certificate.cer";
    $this->mws_private_key = dirname(__FILE__)."/MWS/private.key";
}}
```

And here is my MWS.php

```
private function signData($data) {
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    );
    $descriptorspec[2] = $descriptorspec[1];
    try {
        $opensslCommand = 'openssl smime -sign -signer ' . $this->settings->mws_cert .
            ' -inkey ' . $this->settings->mws_private_key .
            ' -nochain -nocerts -outform PEM -nodetach -passin pass:'.$this->settings->mws_cert_password;
        $this->log->info("opensslCommand: " . $opensslCommand);
        $process = proc_open($opensslCommand, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        if (is_resource($process)) {
            fwrite($pipes[0], $data);
            fclose($pipes[0]);
            $pkcs7 = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
            $this->log->info($pkcs7);
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            $resCode = proc_close($process);
            if ($resCode != 0) {
                $errorMsg = 'OpenSSL call failed:' . $resCode . '\n' . $pkcs7;
                $this->log->info($errorMsg);
                throw new \Exception($errorMsg);
            }
            return $pkcs7;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->log->info($e);
        throw $e;
    }
}

/**
 * Makes XML/PKCS#7 request.
 * @param  string $paymentMethod financial method name
 * @param  array  $data          key-value pairs of request body
 * @return string                response from Yandex.Money in XML format
 */
private function sendXmlRequest($paymentMethod, $data) {
    $body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $body .= '<' . $paymentMethod . 'Request ';
    foreach($data AS $param => $value) {
        $body .= $param . '="' . $value . '" ';
    }
    $body .= '/>';

    return $this->sendRequest($paymentMethod, $this->signData($body), "pkcs7-mime");
}

/**
 * Makes application/x-www-form-urlencoded request.
 * @param  string $paymentMethod financial method name
 * @param  array  $data          key-value pairs of request body
 * @return string                response from Yandex.Money in XML format
 */
private function sendUrlEncodedRequest($paymentMethod, $data) {
    return $this->sendRequest($paymentMethod, http_build_query($data), "x-www-form-urlencoded");
}

/**
 * Sends prepared request.
 * @param  string $paymentMethod financial method name
 * @param  string $requestBody   prepared request body
 * @param  string $contentType   HTTP Content-Type header value
 * @return string                response from Yandex.Money in XML format
 */
private function sendRequest($paymentMethod, $requestBody, $contentType) {
    $this->log->info($paymentMethod . " Request: " . $requestBody);

    $curl = curl_init();
    $params = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/' . $contentType),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://penelope-demo.yamoney.ru:8083/webservice/mws/api/' . $paymentMethod,
        CURLOPT_POST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $this->settings->mws_cert,
        CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $this->settings->mws_private_key,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $this->settings->mws_cert_password,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestBody
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);
    $result = null;
    try {
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($result === false) $result = curl_error($curl);
        $this->log->info("Result: " . $result);
        if (!$result) {
            trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
    $this->log->info("Error: " . $ex);
        echo $ex;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And ListOrder.php

```
<?php
namespace shop;

require_once "../Settings.php";
require_once "MWS.php";

$mws = new MWS(new Settings());

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mws->listOrders()) ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the paths to your files are incorrect

Comment: Which paths are incorrect ? I'm .Net Developer, I don't have not much  experiences about php.

Comment: What usually happens when connecting for the first time - and all goes well - the host is added to the known_hosts file. You can find it where the certs are, typically in ~/.ssh Depending your distro the path may be different. The procedure should be fairly the same though.

Comment: @PHClaus hi friend,

Comment: @PHClaus hi friend,

When i am trying to use yandex's key and certificate i am getting expired error. But when i am trying to use my certificate and private key i am getting above error.

Comment: I take it from there Yandex certs and keys work, albeit they have expired. You have placed your own files in the same location? Backup Yandex and overwrite with your own, then test again. However, unless you add your own to the keyring first even valid certs and keys will likely fail because checksums don't match.

Comment: @PHClaus yes i changed it like u said. But i think my certificate and key is wrong. Then i download .pem file on my plesk and changed curl settings like this, i deleted 
            CURLOPT_SSLKEY => $this->settings->mws_private_key,
            CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => $this->settings->mws_cert_password,

and added above code

            CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE=>'PEM',
            CURLOPT_SSLCERT => $this->settings->mws_cert,

then i get this error
"error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca"

Comment: @PHClaus btw i am working on this url, i have no ssl on my local

http://localhost:63342/untitled/MWS/mws.html?_ijt=n15rni9gsf8lorl4m43mviluga

Comment: Enlighten me, you are working on localhost without SSL? Or are you saying, you are trying it on a live host? Again: You need to add cert and key to the system first. And obviously SSL will never work if the server doesn't have it.

Comment: @PHClaus Hi Friend
Yes i was working on localhost without SSL. I think i know what is the problem now. If you look at this documentation https://tech.yandex.com/money/doc/payment-solution/ssl-docpage/
You will understand what i am trying to make. I created a request.csr and private.key with openssl command. Now i will send the files to Yandex and they will send me .crt file.

But how can i add the chain certificates to .crt (Yandex's sent)
Here is the chain certificates (CA,Root)
[link]http://crls.yamoney.ru/ymca.p7b

Comment: @PHClaus P.S: Now i am working on hosting with SSL.